# how can i handle error if there is error in jwt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

```
   passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
```

In this code,'jwt checks the token.

If an error occurs in this code(which is "jwt"), I want to handle the error. if(error){console.log(err)} like this

then how can i fix my code?

router.post(
"/me",

```
      passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
      async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
          res.status(201).json(fullUserWithoutPassword);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          next(error);
        }
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You added `passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false })` as a middleware to your router. That means that if the `jwt` is invalid (or is not present in the request), the `passport` will automatically return `401` (Unauthorized) `error` message.